# What is the syntax for l.d.o translations in a drush make file

Tags: i18n-l10n, drush

I have read the Drush Make documentation, and understand you can download translations at the time you use the drush make command, since there is an option. What I don't understand clearly is how to add a translation from localize.drupal.org to your .make file. Any help and/or an example would be amazing. Thanks.

Drush Make documentation: http://drupalcode.org/project/drush_make.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/6.x-2.x:/README.txt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The post beta9 dev version of drush_make also supports downloading drupal core translations with, for example:

```
projects[] = nl
```

Source: http://drupal.org/node/644916. (There's also a documentation patch there.)